# JDK 16 Curve not supported: secp256r1 [NIST P-256,X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, google-pay, java-16

Currently working on upgrading from Java 13 to Java 16 and using the following updated dependencies for a cryptography library performing encryption/decryption:

1. BouncyCastle 1.69
2. Google Tink 1.6.1

=================================

Crypto Library class:

```
package com.decryption.test;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Service
public class CryptoLib {

    protected static final String PROTOCOL_VERSION = "ECv2";

    protected final String DEV_ROOT_PUB_KEY = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAESXy7kqanQwAM/HBTcV0MVtgQkKLY6UVqP3Z/vdlxiRgFqnc9dZUSD8muUpgeZDD05lM68qoI31mbeX9c8P/9Uw==";

    protected static final String MERCHANT_ID_PREFIX = "merchant:";

    protected static final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGO = "HmacSha256";

    protected static final int HMAC_SHA256_ALGO_SIZE = 256 / 8; // 256 bit key size -> 32 bytes

    protected static final String AES_CTR_ALGO = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";

    protected static final int AES_CTR_ALGO_SIZE = 256 / 8; // 256 bit key size -> 32 bytes

    protected static final byte[] HKDF_EMPTY_SALT = new byte[0];

    protected static final byte[] AES_CTR_ZERO_IV = new byte[16];

    protected final static String ASYMMETRIC_KEY_TYPE = "EC";

    protected static final String SENDER_ID = "Google";

    protected static final String SECURITY_PROVIDER = "BC";

    protected static final String EC_CURVE = "prime256v1";
    protected static final String CSR_SIGNATURE = "SHA256WITHECDSA";
    protected static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withECDSA";

    @Autowired
    private ProfileManager profileManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadKeys() {
        final StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Loading Google pay signing keys. ");
        if (this.profileManager.isProfileActive("dev")) {
            message.append("Profile DEV is active. Only test rig encrypted payloads supported.");
        } else {
            final GooglePaymentsPublicKeysManager googleKeyManager = this.getGoogleKeyManager();
            googleKeyManager.refreshInBackground();
        }
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private static String getMerchantIdComponent(final String merchantId) {
        return merchantId.startsWith(MERCHANT_ID_PREFIX) ?
                merchantId : MERCHANT_ID_PREFIX + merchantId;
    }


    private GooglePaymentsPublicKeysManager getGoogleKeyManager() {
        return profileManager.isProfileActive("prod") ?
                GooglePaymentsPublicKeysManager.INSTANCE_PRODUCTION :
                GooglePaymentsPublicKeysManager.INSTANCE_TEST;
    }

    public String decrypt(final GoogleDecryptRequest decryptRequest) throws Exception {
        try {
            final PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.Builder builder = new PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.Builder()
                    .protocolVersion(PROTOCOL_VERSION)
                    .recipientId(getMerchantIdComponent(decryptRequest.getMerchantId()));

            if (decryptRequest.getPrivateKey() != null) {
                builder.addRecipientPrivateKey(decryptRequest.getPrivateKey());
            }

            //Add all our retired keys to the list.
            for (final ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey : decryptRequest.getOldPrivateKeys()) {
                builder.addRecipientPrivateKey(ecPrivateKey);
            }

            if (this.profileManager.isProfileActive("dev")) {
                builder.addSenderVerifyingKey(DEV_ROOT_PUB_KEY);
            } else {
                builder.fetchSenderVerifyingKeysWith(getGoogleKeyManager());
            }

            return builder.build()
                    .unseal(decryptRequest.getEncryptedMessage());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            final String errMsg = MessageFormat.format("GooglePay Decryption failed for Google merchant ID [{0}]", decryptRequest.getMerchantId());
            throw new Exception(errMsg, e);
        }
    }


    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class GoogleEncryptRequest implements EncryptRequest<ECPublicKey> {

        /**
         * Merchant public key
         */
        private ECPublicKey publicKey;

        private String algorithm = "EC";

        /**
         * Google merchantID. If the merchant ID is xxx, this value should be either
         * <ul>
         *     <li>xxx</li>
         *     <li>merchant:xxx</li>
         * </ul>
         */
        private String merchantId;
        /**
         * Message to encrypt
         */
        private String message;
    }

    public EncryptResponse encrypt(final GoogleEncryptRequest encryptRequest) throws Exception {

        final String DEV_ROOT_PRIV_KEY = "MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg3lO35/XiUzEooUJlLKEd0BJmoLgeTvkFSm/b4wMrgdWgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAARJfLuSpqdDAAz8cFNxXQxW2BCQotjpRWo/dn+92XGJGAWqdz11lRIPya5SmB5kMPTmUzryqgjfWZt5f1zw//1T";
        final String DEV_ROOT_PUB_KEY = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAESXy7kqanQwAM/HBTcV0MVtgQkKLY6UVqP3Z/vdlxiRgFqnc9dZUSD8muUpgeZDD05lM68qoI31mbeX9c8P/9Uw==";

        final GoogleEncryptResponse response = new GoogleEncryptResponse();

        try {
            //STEP 1: Generate all keys.

            // Generate root keypair. Used to sign intermediate. jsonPath -> $.intermediateSigningKey.signatures
            final PrivateKey rootPrivKey = CryptoUtility.getPrivateFromPKCS8Base64(DEV_ROOT_PRIV_KEY, ASYMMETRIC_KEY_TYPE);
            final PublicKey rootPubKey = CryptoUtility.getPublicFromBase64(DEV_ROOT_PUB_KEY, ASYMMETRIC_KEY_TYPE); //equiv to the verifying key from the test/prod APIs

            // Generate intermediate keypair. Used to sign whole payload. jsonPath -> $.signature
            final KeyPair intermediateKeyPair =  generateKeyPair();
            final PrivateKey intermediatePrivKey = intermediateKeyPair.getPrivate();
            // Convert to uncompressed point and B64 encode. Goes to $.intermediateSigningKey.signedKey.keyValue
            final PublicKey intermediatePubKey = intermediateKeyPair.getPublic();

            // Generate ephemeral pub key. Used to create a shared secret to decrypt the signed message
            final KeyPair ephemeralKeyPair = generateKeyPair();
            final PrivateKey ephemeralPrivKey = ephemeralKeyPair.getPrivate();
            // Convert to uncompressed point and B64 encode. Goes to $.signedMessage.ephemeralPublicKey
            final PublicKey ephemeralPubKey = ephemeralKeyPair.getPublic();
            final byte[] ephemeralPubKeyBytes = getUncompressedPoint(ephemeralPubKey);

            //Parse merchant public key
            final ECPublicKey merchantPublicKey = encryptRequest.getPublicKey();

            /*
            STEP 2: Sign the intermediate key. This step will generate the intermediateSigningKey block in the json
            ECDSA(length_of_sender_id || sender_id || length_of_protocol_version || protocol_version || length_of_signed_key || signed_key)
             */
            final long keyExpiry = Instant.now().plus(365, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli();
            final String intermediatePubKeyB64 = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(intermediatePubKey.getEncoded());
            response.setIntermediateSigningKey(keyExpiry, intermediatePubKeyB64);

            final byte[] senderComponent = getSignatureBytesForComponent(SENDER_ID);
            final byte[] protocolVersionComponent = getSignatureBytesForComponent(PROTOCOL_VERSION);
            final String signingKeyJson = new Gson().toJson(response.getIntermediateSigningKey().getSignedKey());
            final byte[] signingKeyComponent = getSignatureBytesForComponent(signingKeyJson);

            //Assemble all components into one byte array
            final byte[] intermediateSignatureComponentBytes = ByteBuffer
                    .allocate(senderComponent.length + protocolVersionComponent.length + signingKeyComponent.length)
                    .put(senderComponent)
                    .put(protocolVersionComponent)
                    .put(signingKeyComponent)
                    .array();

            //Sign the byte array using ECDSA
            final String intermediateSignature = ecdsaSignMessageB64(rootPrivKey, intermediateSignatureComponentBytes);
            response.setIntermediateSigningKeySignatures(intermediateSignature);

            /*
            Step 3: Create the signed message. Includes tag, encrypted data and ephemeralPubKey
             */

            //Step 3a: Generate shared secret. Used for symmetric encryption
            final byte[] sharedSecret = EllipticCurves.computeSharedSecret(
                    (ECPrivateKey) ephemeralPrivKey,
                    merchantPublicKey.getW());

            //Step 3b: Generate HMAC key and symmetric key using shared secret
            final byte[] eciesKey = Hkdf.computeEciesHkdfSymmetricKey(
                    ephemeralPubKeyBytes,
                    sharedSecret,
                    HMAC_SHA256_ALGO,
                    HKDF_EMPTY_SALT,
                    SENDER_ID.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    HMAC_SHA256_ALGO_SIZE + AES_CTR_ALGO_SIZE //256 bit aes key and 256 bit hmac key
            );
            final byte[] aesKey = Arrays.copyOf(eciesKey, AES_CTR_ALGO_SIZE); // [0,32] bytes
            final byte[] hmacKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(eciesKey, HMAC_SHA256_ALGO_SIZE, HMAC_SHA256_ALGO_SIZE * 2); //[32,64]

            //Step 3c: Encrypt data
            final Cipher cipher = EngineFactory.CIPHER.getInstance(AES_CTR_ALGO);
            cipher.init(
                    Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,
                    new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES"),
                    new IvParameterSpec(AES_CTR_ZERO_IV));
            final byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptRequest.getMessage().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            //Step 3d: Compute HMAC tag
            final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hmacKey, HMAC_SHA256_ALGO);
            final Mac mac = EngineFactory.MAC.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGO);
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            final byte[] hmacBytes = mac.doFinal(cipherBytes);

            //Step 3e: Populate data in response. $.signedMessage
            final String ephemeralPublicKeyB64 = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ephemeralPubKeyBytes);
            final String hmacB64 = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacBytes);
            final String cipherB64 = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherBytes);
            response.setSignedMessage(cipherB64, hmacB64, ephemeralPublicKeyB64);

            /*
            Step 4: Create $.signature using intermediate priv and the serialized signed key
            ECDSA(length_of_sender_id || sender_id || length_of_recipient_id || recipient_id || length_of_protocolVersion || protocolVersion || length_of_signedMessage || signedMessage)
             */

            final String merchantIdComponentString = getMerchantIdComponent(encryptRequest.getMerchantId());
            final byte[] merchantComponent = getSignatureBytesForComponent(merchantIdComponentString);
            ;
            final String signedMessageJson = new Gson().toJson(response.getSignedMessage());
            final byte[] signedMessageComponent = getSignatureBytesForComponent(signedMessageJson);

            //Assemble all components into one byte array
            final int signatureComponentLength = senderComponent.length + merchantComponent.length + protocolVersionComponent.length + signedMessageComponent.length;
            final byte[] signatureComponentBytes = ByteBuffer
                    .allocate(signatureComponentLength)
                    .put(senderComponent)
                    .put(merchantComponent)
                    .put(protocolVersionComponent)
                    .put(signedMessageComponent)
                    .array();

            final String signatureB64 = ecdsaSignMessageB64(intermediatePrivKey, signatureComponentBytes);
            response.setSignature(signatureB64);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Encryption failed: " +  e);
        }
        return response;
    }



    static byte[] getSignatureBytesForComponent(final String component) {
        final byte[] componentLengthBytes = ByteBuffer
                .allocate(4)
                .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                .putInt(component.length())
                .array();
        final byte[] componentBytes = ByteBuffer
                .wrap(component.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .array();
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(componentLengthBytes.length + componentBytes.length)
                .put(componentLengthBytes)
                .put(componentBytes)
                .array();
    }

    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws Exception {
        try {
            final KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ASYMMETRIC_KEY_TYPE, SECURITY_PROVIDER);
            kpg.initialize(generateECParameterSpec());
            return kpg.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to generate ECC KeyPair. " + e);
            throw new Exception("Failed to generate ECC KeyPair.");
        }
    }

    protected static ECNamedCurveSpec generateECParameterSpec() {
        final ECNamedCurveParameterSpec bcParams = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(EC_CURVE);
        final ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec(bcParams.getName(), bcParams.getCurve(),
                bcParams.getG(), bcParams.getN(), bcParams.getH(), bcParams.getSeed());
        return params;
    }



    private static String ecdsaSignMessageB64(final PrivateKey privateKey, final byte[] messageToSign) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException {
        final Signature intermediateECDSASignature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        intermediateECDSASignature.initSign(privateKey);
        intermediateECDSASignature.update(messageToSign);
        final byte[] intermediateSignatureBytes = intermediateECDSASignature.sign();
        return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(intermediateSignatureBytes);

    }

    public static byte[] getUncompressedPoint(final PublicKey publicKey) {
        final java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey pub = (java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey) publicKey;
        return pub.getEncoded();
    }

    @Component
    public class ProfileManager {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @PostConstruct
        public void setup() {
            System.out.println(this.getActiveProfiles());
        }

        public boolean isProfileActive(final String profile) {
            for (final String activeProfile : this.environment.getActiveProfiles()) {
                if (activeProfile.equalsIgnoreCase(profile)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public List<String> getActiveProfiles() {
            return List.of(this.environment.getActiveProfiles());
        }

    }
    @Slf4j
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class GoogleEncryptResponse implements EncryptResponse {

        //These entities represent the structure provided by the GPay spec. See link in class docs
        private String protocolVersion = "ECv2";

        private String signature;

        private IntermediateSigningKey intermediateSigningKey = new IntermediateSigningKey();

        private SignedMessage signedMessage = new SignedMessage();

        public void setIntermediateSigningKey(final long keyExpiration, final String keyValue) {
            this.intermediateSigningKey.getSignedKey().setKeyExpiration(Long.toString(keyExpiration));
            this.intermediateSigningKey.getSignedKey().setKeyValue(keyValue);
        }

        public void setIntermediateSigningKeySignatures(final String... signatures) {
            this.intermediateSigningKey.setSignatures(signatures);
        }

        public void setSignedMessage(final String encryptedMessage, final String tag, final String ephemeralPublicKey) {
            this.signedMessage.setEncryptedMessage(encryptedMessage);
            this.signedMessage.setTag(tag);
            this.signedMessage.setEphemeralPublicKey(ephemeralPublicKey);
        }

        @Override
        public String getResult() {
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            JsonObject intermediateSigningKeyJson = new JsonObject();
            JsonArray intermediateSigningKeyJsonSignatures = new JsonArray();
            Arrays.stream(intermediateSigningKey.getSignatures())
                    .forEach(intermediateSigningKeyJsonSignatures::add);
            intermediateSigningKeyJson.add("signatures", intermediateSigningKeyJsonSignatures);
            intermediateSigningKeyJson.addProperty("signedKey", gson.toJson(getIntermediateSigningKey().getSignedKey()));

            JsonObject payloadRoot = new JsonObject();
            payloadRoot.addProperty("protocolVersion", protocolVersion);
            payloadRoot.addProperty("signature", signature);
            payloadRoot.add("intermediateSigningKey", intermediateSigningKeyJson);
            payloadRoot.addProperty("signedMessage", gson.toJson(getSignedMessage()));

            return getJsonElementHtmlSafe(payloadRoot);
        }


        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        public static class IntermediateSigningKey {
            private SignedKey signedKey = new SignedKey();

            /**
             * Signatures signed by the verifying key. Should be B64 encoded used SHA256 hashing with
             * ECDSA
             */
            private String[] signatures;

            @Data
            @NoArgsConstructor
            static class SignedKey {

                /**
                 * A Base64 version of key encoded in ASN.1 type.
                 * aka, der format. key.getEncoded()
                 */
                private String keyValue;

                /**
                 * Date and time when the intermediate key expires as UTC milliseconds since epoch
                 */
                private String keyExpiration;
            }
        }

        @Setter
        @NoArgsConstructor
        private static class SignedMessage {

            /**
             * A Base64-encoded encrypted message that contains payment information
             */
            private String encryptedMessage;

            /**
             * A Base64-encoded ephemeral public key associated
             * with the private key to encrypt the message in uncompressed point format
             */
            private String ephemeralPublicKey;

            /**
             * A Base64-encoded MAC of encryptedMessage.
             */
            private String tag;

        }
    }

    public interface EncryptResponse {

        String getResult();

    }

    public interface EncryptRequest<K extends PublicKey> {

        /**
         * Public key used to encrypt
         * @return
         */
        K getPublicKey();

        void setPublicKey(K publicKey);

        String getAlgorithm();

        /**
         * Set the PublicKey object using a base64 encoded key.
         * @param base64EncodedKey
         */
        default void setPublicKey(final String base64EncodedKey) throws Exception {
            PublicKey publicKey = CryptoUtility.getPublicFromBase64(base64EncodedKey, getAlgorithm());
            setPublicKey((K) publicKey);
        }

        /**
         * Message to encrypt
         * @return
         */
        String getMessage();
    }

    public static String getJsonElementHtmlSafe(JsonElement element) {
        try {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter);
            jsonWriter.setLenient(false);
            jsonWriter.setHtmlSafe(true); //Ensures '=' will appear as \u003d

            Streams.write(element, jsonWriter);
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Builder
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class GoogleDecryptRequest implements DecryptRequest<ECPrivateKey> {

        /**
         * This represents the encrypted value
         */
        private String encryptedMessage;

        /**
         * The current active private key
         */
        private ECPrivateKey privateKey;

        /**
         * These privateKey represents a private key that may have been rotated recently.
         * May be empty
         */
        @Singular
        private List<ECPrivateKey> oldPrivateKeys = new ArrayList<>();

        /**
         * Corresponds to the GPay console merchant id
         * Value must be prefixed with merchant:<br/>
         * For example: merchant:1234345345345
         */
        private String merchantId;

        private String algorithm = "EC";

        public void addOldPrivateKey(final ECPrivateKey privateKey) {
            this.oldPrivateKeys.add(privateKey);
        }

        public static class GoogleDecryptRequestBuilder {

            public GoogleDecryptRequestBuilder encryptedMessage(final String encryptedMessage) {
                try {
                    final JsonElement jsonPayload = new JsonParser().parse(encryptedMessage);
                    this.encryptedMessage = getJsonElementHtmlSafe(jsonPayload);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to parse GooglePay encrypted message. Data MUST be a valid json string." + e);
                }
                return this;
            }

        }
    }

    public interface DecryptRequest<K extends PrivateKey> {

        /**
         * Return the message that will be decrypted.
         * @return
         */
        String getEncryptedMessage();

        /**
         * Return the private key required for decryption
         * @return
         */
        K getPrivateKey();

        void setPrivateKey(K privateKey);

        String getAlgorithm();

        /**
         * Set the PublicKey object using a base64 encoded key.
         * @param base64EncodedKey
         */
        default void setPrivateKey(final String base64EncodedKey) throws Exception {
            PrivateKey privateKey = CryptoUtility.getPrivateFromPKCS8Base64(base64EncodedKey, getAlgorithm());
            setPrivateKey((K) privateKey);
        }

    }


}
```

CryptoUtility class:

```
package com.decryption.test;

public class CryptoUtility {

    public static PrivateKey getPrivateFromPKCS8Base64(final String base64, final String algorithm) throws Exception {
        final byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.decode(base64);
        return getPrivateFromPKCS8Der(privateKeyBytes, algorithm);
    }
    public static PrivateKey getPrivateFromPKCS8Der(final byte[] privateKeyBytes, final String algorithm) throws Exception {
        try {
            final PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
            final KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm, CryptoLib.SECURITY_PROVIDER);
            return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to created Private Key." + e);
        }
    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicFromBase64(final String base64, final String algorithm) throws Exception {
        final byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.decode(base64);
        return getPublicFromDer(publicKeyBytes, algorithm);
    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicFromDer(final byte[] publicKeyBytes, final String algorithm) throws Exception {
        try {
            final X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes, algorithm);
            final KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm, CryptoLib.SECURITY_PROVIDER);
            return kf.generatePublic(spec);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to created Public Key from string value" + e);
        }
    }






}
```

JUnit class:

```
package com.decryption.test;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DecryptionTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CryptoLib googleECCCryptoLibrary;

    @Mock
    private CryptoLib.ProfileManager profileManager;


    @Test
    void encryptAndDecryptMockData() throws Exception {
        final ECPrivateKey merchantPrivKey = (ECPrivateKey) CryptoUtility.getPrivateFromPKCS8Base64("MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgsfylDy+Q3lfR6nbipZGDZWzp6P+qiQeApJizxG/hj96gCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAQg1SVNuof6FndzJkbPst37moW+L/36EPLiiosS5BBSsLK4q2aLxzk2M732OpDHkXTp31ZQitPDQImndaY57ZSM", "EC");
        final ECPublicKey merchantPubKey = (ECPublicKey) CryptoUtility.getPublicFromBase64("MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEINUlTbqH+hZ3cyZGz7Ld+5qFvi/9+hDy4oqLEuQQUrCyuKtmi8c5NjO99jqQx5F06d9WUIrTw0CJp3WmOe2UjA==", "EC");

        final CryptoLib.GoogleEncryptRequest encRequest = CryptoLib.GoogleEncryptRequest.builder()
                .merchantId("12345678901234567890")
                .message("heyhey!")
                .publicKey(merchantPubKey)
                .build();
        final CryptoLib.EncryptResponse encResponse = googleECCCryptoLibrary.encrypt(encRequest);

        final CryptoLib.GoogleDecryptRequest decryptRequest = CryptoLib.GoogleDecryptRequest.builder()
                .privateKey(merchantPrivKey)
                .merchantId("12345678901234567890")
                .encryptedMessage(encResponse.getResult())
                .build();


        given(this.profileManager.isProfileActive(anyString())).willReturn(true);

        final String decResponse = this.googleECCCryptoLibrary.decrypt(decryptRequest);
        assertEquals(encRequest.getMessage(), decResponse);
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
    Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Curve not supported: secp256r1 [NIST P-256,X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.subtle.EllipticCurves.computeSharedSecret(EllipticCurves.java:963)
```

**ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret()** implementation seems to be changed in Java 16 where it is now throwing:
*throw new IllegalStateException(new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("Curve not supported*
as compared to the implementation in Java 13.

Any recommendations to implement encryption in JDK 16 with BouncyCastle as the provider or if it should be replaced by any other provider?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but we experimented with solutions to this a few months back (with a project run by java 1.6). The most straight-forward solution to get around the `"Curve not supported: secp256r1" ` error (and the one we went with) is changing the project to run with java 11.